# Jsoup - improve extracting images from html page

Tags: java, html, image, jsoup

I'm getting images from the web using these lines of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i++){ 
        try{
            doc=Jsoup.connect(links.get(i)).userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(0).get();
            Elements links=doc.getElementsByTag("img");
            imageLink=links.get(3).toString();
            String[] bits=imageLink.split("\"");
            imageLink=bits[1];
            System.out.println(imageLink);
            url=new URL(imageLink);
            image=ImageIO.read(url);
            images.add(image);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This code works great but it's really slow. I get like one image per second and I need at least half the time. Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
imageLink=links.get(3).toString();
String[] bits=imageLink.split("\"");
imageLink=bits[1];
```

With this:

```
imageLink = links.get(3).attr("src");
```

Read more about extracting attributes here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html